# How can I add configuration files to a Spark job running in YARN-CLUSTER mode?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark 1.6.0. I want to upload a files using --files tag and read the file content after initializing the spark context.

My spark-submit command syntax looks like below:

```
spark-submit \
  --deploy-mode yarn-cluster \
  --files /home/user/test.csv \
  /home/user/spark-test-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I read the Spark documentation and it suggested me to use SparkFiles.get("test.csv") but this is not working in *yarn-cluster* mode.
If I change the deploy mode to *local*, the code works fine but I get a file not found exception in **yarn-cluster** mode.

I can see in logs that my files is uploaded to **hdfs://host:port/user/guest/.sparkStaging/application_1452310382039_0019/test.csv** directory and the SparkFiles.get is trying to look for file in **/tmp/test.csv** which is not correct. If someone has successfully used this, please help me solve this.

Comment: The question had a native answer for yarn-client mode. I have updated the question and changed the mode to yarn-cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Spark submit command

```
spark-submit \
  --deploy-mode yarn-client \
  --files /home/user/test.csv \
  /home/user/spark-test-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/user/test.csv
```

Read file in main program

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val fis = new FileInputStream(args(0));
    // read content of file
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can we achieve this in yarn-cluster mode

Comment: change yarn-client to yarn-cluster, everything will be remain same.

Comment: I assume this will not work. I tested it and it failed. Since the driver is running on a different node, it will not be able to read local files.